# nv-pro samples compiling failure, the global scope has no "int_least8_t"

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, opengl-4

Trying to get [this sample](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_commandlist_basic) from the nvidia repository working, I followed the instructions they give:

- cloned *gl_commandlist_basic*, *shared_external*, *shared_sources* and *build_all*, all of them at the same level (same directory)
- `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"` inside *build_all*
- opened `ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` with vs2015 CE and built

[image]

Complete output:

https://gist.github.com/elect86/a5272f2350e746d22f0352553d55669d

most of errors look like:

```
error C2039: 'int_least8_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C2873: 'int_least8_t': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

[Here](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_vk_threaded_cadscene/issues/2#issuecomment-217535433) there is an issue on another sample of the same suite with exactly the same error. One of the user suggests it is a problem coming from a bad mixing of C and C++

Trying to google, I didn't get much luck, none of the result seems to have a clear resolution and they are strictly related to something else

So, what's the problem, guys?

**For the downvoters:**

*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

- Questions seeking debugging help -> I am seeking *compiling* help, it's a little different. If you don't know the difference, I suggest you to refer to wikipedia, reading the [compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation) and [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) definitions
- desired behaviour -> getting the sample compiled
- a specific problem or error -> hundreds of:

  ```
  error C2039: 'int_least8_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''
  error C2873: 'int_least8_t': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
  ```

  You can see the complete output in the link posted previously
- shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself -> follow the instructions in the README.md, that is also my steps listed above

Continuing choosing to close the question with the same motivation without even trying to reply to my observations does not help anyone else except your own ego

**Edit:**
So at the end you made it in closing the question without any constructive feedback, not bad. Only exception is one unique comment, although it is kind of funny because the guy explicitly admits it's because a false perceived laziness, nevertheless he didn't reply any further.. on the contrary he even voted to close the question down... lmao

even more interesting, they appear to be so lazy to read over a link put at begin, but not enough to scroll down and choose to close the question..

Not bad at all, guys, excellent support!

God, every time I have to face the C/C++ community is always a bloodbath...

**Edit2:**
Will Perone (@Nvidia) wanted to respond, but he doesn't have enough reputation, so I quote his words:

> the answer there is on the right track.  There is a stdint.h in
>   nvpro-samples\shared_external\NSight for compatibility with old
>   versions of visual studio in there.  You can just delete that and it
>   should all work.  I'm going to follow up with the maintainer of the
>   repo.
>    I haven't tested that solution with earlier versions of visual studio but it should work in 15.  Will see if I 
>   can get the maintainer to do an official fix for it.  I think it's
>   because some of the samples were made before VS 15 came out and not
>   updated.

Comment: Downvotes are probably due to perceived lazily posting a link to your code rather than including it in your post. The link is right at the start of your post and people probably don't read past it.

Comment: Which link do you mean? The sample link or the output one? Because actually none one refers to any of my code (given the nature of the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is (possibly) caused by the NSight integration. There used to be a legacy stdint.h in there but this was removed some time ago.
Try removing _addPackageNSight from the CMake and rebuilding. 
Also make sure you pull the latest shared_sources and shared_external.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, commenting out `_add_package_NSight()` inside `gl_commandlist_basic\CMakeList.txt` made it compiling!